# Evaluating $\int_{(c)}\frac{x^{s}}{s^{k+1}}ds$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Here, $(c)$ is the path $c+it$, $c\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, $-\infty < t < \infty $ oriented 'upwards', $x$ is a positive real number and $k$ is a positive integer. The answer is given as $0$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $\frac{2\pi i}{k!}\log(x)^{k}$ for $x\geq 1$. The factor $2\pi i$ suggests to me that I should use Cauchy's residue theorem. Indeed, if I am correct, the residue of the integrand at zero is $\lim\limits_{s\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{k!}\frac{d^{k}}{ds^{k}}x^{s}=\frac{1}{k!}\log(x)^{k}$. Therefore, integrating around a contour enclosing zero would give $\frac{2\pi i}{k!}\log(x)^{k}$. This reasoning appears to be in the right direction, but I don't know how to evaluate it over the given path rather than a closed contour, nor how the integral evaluates in a piecewise fashion.

Comment: Have you tried using the [path integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_integration#For_continuous_functions) $${\displaystyle \int _{\gamma }f(z)\,dz=\int _{a}^{b}f{\big (}\gamma (t){\big )}\gamma '(t)\,dt.}$$?

Comment: I have, I don't see how it makes it any easier (although in theory of course I should be able to evaluate it, I just cannot see how). Starting by parameterizing $\gamma (t)=c+it$ so that $\gamma '(t)=i$. Then our integral is equal to \begin{equation}
\int_{\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{ix^{c+it}}{(c+it)^{k+1}}dt.
\end{equation}
I could factor out $ix^{c}$ but would then be unsure how to proceed.

Comment: And "slowly, but firmly" start using [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) ... the pattern should reveal itself, after 2 or 3 iterations.

Comment: Okay I believe I am on the cusp of the answer now. I get various square brackets which vanish in the limit as $R\rightarrow\infty$ of \begin{equation} \int_{-R}^{R}\frac{ix^{c+it}}{(c+it)^{k+1}}dt \end{equation} along with \begin{equation} ix^{c}\frac{log(x)^{k}}{k!}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{x^{it}}{c+it}dt. \end{equation} Plugging the last integral into Wolfram Alpha gives a nice factor of $-ix^{-c}$ and an exponential integral Ei. I admit I've not come across this before and believe it arises from differentiating the complex logarithm?